# Cannot template BaseOperator fields: task_id

Tags: python, airflow

Our team is currently attempting to upgrade Airflow from version 2.2.5 to 2.6.3, and we are encountering an issue with DAG generation.

The error we're facing is as follows:

`airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Cannot template BaseOperator fields: task_id`

Here's an example of a test DAG that triggers the error:

```
DAG_ID="TestDAG"
with models.DAG(dag_id=DAG_ID,
                description="Description",
                default_args={**default_dag_settings, **{"catchup": False,
                                                         "start_date": datetime(2023, 5, 23)}},
                schedule_interval="0 5 * * *",
                doc_md=get_doc_dags(DAG_ID)) as dag:

    my_task = YamlOperator(
        task_id="task_id",
        trigger=TriggerETLConfigUrl(
            "{{ ds }}",
            GCSLoader(
                file_path="file_path").url(),
            "{{ ds }}",
        ),
        dag=dag
    )
```

The YamlOperator class has the following **init** method:

```
class YamlOperator(BaseOperator):
    
    template_fields = ["args", "task_id", "arguments"]
    trigger = None

    def __init__(self,
                 task_id: str,
                 trigger: BaseTrigger,
                 files=None,
                 arguments=None,
                 *args, **kwargs
                 ):
        super(YamlOperator, self).__init__(task_id=task_id, *args, **kwargs)
        self.task_id = task_id
        self.trigger = trigger
        self.files = files
        self.args = self.trigger.command_line_args()
        self.arguments = arguments
```

Could you please provide insights into why this problem might be occurring?

Please, help me to fix it

Answer (score 1):

[BaseOperator parameters](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/baseoperator/index.html#airflow.models.baseoperator.BaseOperator) cannot be templated. The exception you are seeing is an [explicit check to forbid templating those fields](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/eb24742d5300d2d87b17b4bcd67f639dbafd9818/airflow/serialization/serialized_objects.py#L836-L840) specifically.

Template fields are only useful for task execution. Jinja templates/expressions are evaluated *just before* executing a task.

The Scheduler, DAGFileProcessor, and other components need to know the value of BaseOperator parameters prior to task execution for many reasons. For example with `task_id`, there are parsing checks to ensure there are no duplicate task IDs within DAGs. The actual value of `task_id` needs need to known outside of task execution. So the rendering of the Jinja expressions would not occur for the check to be performed properly.

Scenarios like the one described above and others related to scheduling and configuration (like `pool`, `queue`, and the like) is why those types of parameters cannot be templated.